# Change excel box with click to multiple colors then clear

Tags: vba, excel, click

I am working on a project for an internship and part of the request in the file is that I be able to change the color of excel boxes with just a double click.

There is a yes, no and NA box.  SO what I want is to be able to change the color of a box from red, to green, to grey, and then back to clear. I have an initial double click and then it changes as you click. Here's what I have so far which takes me from red to green.  Thanks for any help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick( _
        ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
' This macro is activated when you doubleclick
' on a cell on a worksheet.
' Purpose: color or decolor the cell when clicked on again
      If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            ' if cell is already red, make the cell green
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      Else
            ' make the cell red:
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End If
      ' true to cancel the 'editing' mode of a cell:
      Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you can just add an `ElseIf` with the same type of logic to tet you from green to gray (and another for gray back to red?), since it's always in the same sequence

Comment: I would use `Target.Interior.Color` and a fixed `RGB()` value instead of `ColorIndex`, or your colors may not be consistent across users.

Comment: Bonus points for making right click go backwards!

Answer (score 0):

ColorIndex values are not proper below, change them as you need. 
`Case Else` added to color empty cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
        Case 3
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Case 4
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Case 5
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Case Else
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End Select
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```